# progressbar in the middle of a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-button, android-progressbar

I want to create a progress bar **in the middle** of a standard button, something like this : 
[image: progressbar]

In the xml layout, when i click the progressbar, i do see that it's located where i wish it to be, but on realtime, i can't see it, it feels like its hiding below the button.
[image: android studio xml]

I've tried :

1. Changing the view's positioning (button above/below progressbar)
2. indeterminate
3. Playing with ProgressBar's style

Nothing seemed to be working.

Here's my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:text="test button" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: maybe because you need to change the color of progress bar

Comment: tried different colors before, its not it.

Comment: add these to your theme base  style<item name="colorControlActivated">#ffff4444</item>
 <item name="colorControlNormal">#ff0099cc</item> and try it again

Comment: Just a user-minded comment: that looks horrible. At least hide the text.

Comment: @m0skit0 obviously... thats just an example, made on some random paint program

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is related with `elevation`. Add `elevation` to the ProgressBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:text="test button" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: perfect. forgot about that. just adding elevation to the progressbar did the trick. even thought elevation is only from api 21.

Comment: Why is that Elevation problem? Elevation solve the problem . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the Preview, the ProgressBar is always invisible (at least to me).

The problem is, that you applied an elevation to your button. this changes the z-level of a view. So the ProgressBar really is behind your button, because the ProgressBar does not have an elevation.

Giving the ProgressBar an elevation of 3dp worked for me.

```xml
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_id"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_id"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

EDIT:
You will be better of, using a [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html).

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.setMessage("Wait...");
dialog.show();
```

Comment: why should i use the progressdialog if i can only do it elegantly in the xml, without any code behind ?

Comment: because I do not find it very "elegantly". Setting your ProgressBar to visible/invisible is not much less code, than showing a ProgressDialog.

Comment: ProgressDialog id deprecated from api 26 and it is recommended to use ProgressBar

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to support devices older than 21 (thus can't use `android:elevation`), try wrapping your button in another dummy layout. I'm using `FrameLayout` as an example.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white" />
</FrameLayout>
```